# To use the license of Ubuntu Font face, what specifically i have to cite in my website?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family, license

I want to use the fonts available in http://font.ubuntu.com/ in my personal website, but I dont know what text I  have to include in "Legal Information & Notices" section of my website. I have found [This](http://font.ubuntu.com/licence/) but I have doubt if are this text, part of this, or another. Thank You :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've read the licence you link to and I think you're quite okay to use the font freely on your website. The following parts of the licence are relevant:

> The requirement for fonts to remain under this licence does not
>   require any document created using the fonts or their derivatives to
>   be published under this licence, as long as the primary purpose of the
>   document is not to be a vehicle for the distribution of the fonts.

I would say that for the purposes of this clause, your website is a 'document'.

Next relevant part:

> The Ubuntu Font Family is presently distributed under the Ubuntu Font
>   Licence. This means you can use the font in much the same way as you
>   would use any other font (open or proprietary).

This is pretty much self-explanatory - note the explicit reference to using the font as you would any other.

Last up is this:

> You are most welcome to use the Ubuntu Font Family, in your documents,
>   graphic designs, logos, or company stationary. We'd like as many
>   people as possible to have a better quality reading experience
>   everyday.

Again, I would class web pages as 'documents'. Support is lent to this interpretation by the fact that there's no exclusion of web pages from the lists given in the extracts above.

In conclusion, I think you're free to use the font on your website.

PS: I am a lawyer.

EDIT: you don't have to put a reference to the licence on your website. You might want to attribute the font to Ubuntu, but you're not obliged to.

Comment: So are you saying he does not need to put any notice as to the font used?

Comment: I don't need to cite any part of the license, copyrights, etc? But, if some people want to take the fonts without my knowledge?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I was about to edit to make that clear.

Comment: I don't know how (technically) people can take the fonts from your website - they'd need the font files themselves for that? - but it's not your problem. Canonical have put the fonts out there under a liberal licence, so the people who would 'take the fonts' from your website could instead simply download them as you would do.